# Mailchimp embed form: too many recent signup requests on iOS 10 devices

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, mailchimp

***(Update on this below)***

On a website we're using the naked embed signup form from Mailchimp in unaltered form to let visitors sign up for a mailing list.

For a lot of users this is working fine. But a substantial amount of users report getting the error:

> 'recipient 'xxx' has too many recent signup requests'

We did a test with 25 friends. 15 of them could subscribe, 10 of them got the error (9 of them used iphone/ipad with iOS 10). That's a lot of missed subscribers.

Also the error doesn't always appear, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

We've emailed Mailchimp and they suggested removing the hidden anti spam field, because they thought some browsers might fill that field with autofill and trigger the spam filter. We tried this, but the same iPhone/iPad users still can't subscribe to the list. So this does not seem to be the solution.

We also tried the solutions described at this websites:

- https://brianhogg.com/avoid-mailchimp-too-many-attempts-signup-error/
- https://medium.com/@CodingJoe/what-to-do-when-youve-accidentally-become-a-celebrity-and-you-get-this-mailchimp-error-recipient-98b1f0bbbe0c#.2ygbrfwn7

The first website suggests the same as Mailchimp did. The second website suggests a different approach, but this led to getting the error on all other browsers/devices that were previously working fine, only not on iPhone/Safari.

This is the code we're using:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<form action="//jacquelinemaschino.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=294b4d18f697aff506b9eb34a&amp;id=ab37464845" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="formulier mailchimp validate" target="_blank" novalidate>


<div class="form-field">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">E-mailadres </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_294b4d18f697aff506b9eb34a_ab37464845" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>

    <div class="form-buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="Blijf op de hoogte en schrijf je in" class="button button-3" name="mmc_subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">
    </div>

</form>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

We've searched the entire internet for a solution but we just can't find one. That's why I hope someone here might have experience with this problem or can find a problem with the website itself. The form can be found on http://inclusiefondernemerschap.nl.

Thanks for any help!

## UPDATE 17 JAN 2017:

After some investigation we've tracked down the issue is not at Mailchimp's side, but some code in the form that makes iOS10 iPhones show the *'Recipient "" has too many recent signup requests'* error.

We're almost there, but as we don't have a iOS10 device to test with (we asked friends) so it's hard to test for us.

We came to the conclusion that:

- This form triggers the error on iOS10 devices: http://van-vlerken.nl/form-en/form3en.html
- This form works good, and doesn't triggers the error: http://van-vlerken.nl/form-en/form4en.html

So, some HTML code in the first form triggers the error. But we're unable to test any further. Can someone else test this, and maybe alter the HTML code to see what exactly triggers the error?

*(Note; the form mentioned above only does a post to the result page which shows a `print_r($_POST)`. No information is send to me, mailchimp or anyone else.)*

*(Note 2: The iPhone emulator at https://appetize.io/demo won't trigger the error at all, so that emulator is unfortunately unusable in this case)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found that removing `target="_blank"` from the `<form>` tag fixed the 'Recipient "" has too many...' error.

Comment: Yes, we also came to this conclusion! Thanks for reporting. Marked your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the link (**shorter URL**) under signup form>Create forms>copy URL in Mailchimp and use that link in place of the existing one.

Try including the protocol in the link too (**HTTP** or **HTTPS**)

Hope this helps.